# Declare variables inside loops the right way?

Tags: c++, loops, declaration

I am trying to declare variables inside a loop, I did some research but still don't know which is the best way to achieve it.

My code so far:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<something.size(); i++){
        char name[2];
        itoa (i, name,10);
        bool Do+name = bool_function(somedata+name); //<- bool Do+name is the new variable
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? also what are you expecting by adding a boolean with a char array?

Comment: @EdChum i have a 5 different somedata , that will be checked with bool_function and i need 5 results bool Do1 Do2 Do3.. Do5

Comment: You can't have `+` in a variable name.

Comment: @zenith i am trying to convert it from python and i am new to c++ i don't know a proper way of doing this

Comment: You probably want a bool array. (Or vector actually)

Comment: There's no way to have _"dynamic"_ variable names that are determined at runtime. The closest thing you can get is probably a `std::map<std::string,bool>` or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395) in the comments, you can't create new variable names dynamically at runtime in C++. All variable names must be known at compile-time. What you need to do here is use array indices instead.

For example, change `somedata` and `Do` to `std::vector`s. Something like this:

```
std::vector<bool> Do(5); // contains 5 bools, all initialized to false

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < something.size(); i++) {
        Do[i] = bool_function(somedata[i]);
}
```

It's worth noting that `std::vector<bool>` is optimized for space: each element will occupy one bit, instead of `sizeof(bool)`. This is okay for non-performance-critical stuff.

Comment: Is it possible to create it like std::vector<bool> Do(something.size()); ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on situation. if you have a huge loop you might face some performance issues because of creating local variables too often. If it is not the case then it might be a good practice to localise your code as much as possible and declare variables only at the moment when you need them.

Btw, are you sure that `char[2]` is big enough to store string representation of your `i` variable. I believe that since `i` is bigger then `9` you will have some problems.

Comment: The loop will go to max 9 at the moment , just to get it working.
My problem is this loop is inside a function that is called from main , and I don't really know the size of something.size(), it is random each time. I was thinking there is a better way to create bool's instead of declaring them before all this bool d1,d2,d3..